# Sequence of boolean operations with the following truth table

Tags: language-agnostic, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, boolean-logic, bitmask

What would be a sequence of boolean operations with the following truth table:

```
mask | target | result
======================
  0  |   0    |   0
  0  |   1    |   0
  1  |   0    |   1
  1  |   1    |   0
```

In a nutshell, that would be "toggle when mask bit is true, clear when mask bit is false".

---

Now some context:

I am designing a turning signal with Arduino, and I am setting current blinking lights with a bit mask, using just two bits:

```
typedef enum ACTIVE_LIGHTS {
    NONE        = 0,  // 00
    RIGHT_LIGHT = 1,  // 01
    LEFT_LIGHT  = 2,  // 10
    BOTH        = 3   // 11
};
```

Now one requirement is this: when I run, say, `toggleLeft()` method, I want to clear the right bit, and toggle the left one.

I tried both ways, but didn't work as desired (mask is always RIGHT_LIGHT or LEFT_LIGHT):

```
target ^= mask; //this toggles one side but doesn't turn the other off
target = mask;  //this turns other side off, but never turns off same side
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about ANDing the light to turn off with 0 (X1 AND 10 = X0), and XORing the light to toggle with 1 (0X XOR 10 = 1X)?

Edit: final answer

Looks like the only time a 1 is output is when mask bit is 1 and input bit is 0, so the function is something like out = mask AND NOT in, for each bit.

Comment: Yeah, I know I could decompose the operation, but a clever one liner is always something to strive for :)

Comment: That is true! It's always satisfying to come up with a short, clever way of doing something. I'll keep thinking about it; it's hard to make a Karnaugh map on mobile!

Comment: Looks like the only time a 1 is output is when mask bit is 1 and input bit is 0, so the function is something like out = mask AND NOT in, for each bit. Does that help?

Comment: I edited the question to include a visual truth table. Still testing here.

Comment: Got it working with your tip! The final expression I used is: `_sides_to_turn = lightSide & ~_sides_to_turn;` Got trouble earlier because I am new to C++ and used `foo & !bar` and `foo && !bar` without success - of course, they are logical, not bitwise operators... Please edit your answer so that I can accept it! Thank you very much! :D

Comment: Edited, glad I was useful! :)